# Error with android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

Tags: android

Sorry for my bad english, I have error which I can't see beacause I missclicked "delete" but I remember that was something with "=" char.

Here's the code, can anyone help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/businessdisaster">

    </ImageView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/startselector">
    </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/exitselector">
    </ImageButton>

        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Don't give alignparent bottom and margin bottom at the same time, instead of margin bottom try giving padding bottom.see whether it helps.also orientation attribute doesn't works for relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

What is this? Your xml is Not well formatted

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

### Solution

You must do it like this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Answer (score -1):

RelativeLayout does not have 'orientation' attribute. Try to remove that.